# How to link JavaScript file to Master/Content Pages in ASP .Net?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, master-pages

I am trying to print the value of selected drop down item into a label without posting back the page by means of JavaScript. I tried linking my JavaScript file to my master page as follows but it is not working. I have included the master and content pages as well as my JavaScript files below. Do I have to link the JavaScript file to the content page as well?

`master page`

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MyMaster.master.cs" Inherits="CodingTest2.MyMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>UHCL</title>
    <script src="JavaScript.js"></script>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolderHead" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/uhclbanner.jpg" Height="154px" Width="950px"/>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal" StaticMenuItemStyle-ItemSpacing="50px">
            <StaticMenuItemStyle BorderColor="Green" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="2px" HorizontalPadding="20px"/>
            <Items>
                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/ComputingStudents.aspx" Text="Computing Students" Value="Computing Students"></asp:MenuItem>
                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/CourseHistory.aspx" Text="Course History" Value="Course History"></asp:MenuItem>
            </Items>
        </asp:Menu>
        <br />
        <br />
        <div>
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

`content page`

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MyMaster.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="CourseHistory.aspx.cs" Inherits="CodingTest2.CourseHistory" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolderHead" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownStuID" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceStuIDs" DataTextField="stuid" DataValueField="stuid" onchange="ddlSelectID(this)">

    </asp:DropDownList>
    <br />
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceStuIDs" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:c432018fa01g1ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT stuid from STUDENT WHERE major='CSC' OR
major='CIS';"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    <br />
    <asp:ListBox ID="ListBoxCourses" runat="server"></asp:ListBox>
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="lblCourses" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="lblErrorMessage" runat="server" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
    <br />
</asp:Content>
```

`JavaScript file`

```
function ddlSelectID(ddl) {
    var lbl = document.getElementById('lblCourses');
    lbl.innerText = ddl.value;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, if you want check whether the JS file is included or not, please press F12 in browser and check the Source; I guess the JS you created has been inlcuded;

Second, according to your code example, the reason why not work is: you get the label by ID: `lblCourses`, but actually, the label ID isn't `lblCourses` at the runtime;

You have two option:
1. Make the label with static ID mode in content page:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblCourses" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:Label>
```

2. Or, Get the dynamic ID in the js function in js file:

```
var lbl = document.getElementById('<%=lblCourses.ClientID%>');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function ddlSelectID() {
var ddlReport = document.getElementById("<%=DropDownStuID.ClientID%>");
    var lbl = document.getElementById('<%=lblCourses.ClientID%>');
    lbl.innerText = ddlReport.options[ddlReport.selectedIndex].value;
}
```

1) This javascript function needs to be called on your page. Usually, this will happen when a button is clicked on clientside. ( OnClientClick method) or bind this function when the items in dropdownlist are changed. 
2) Make changes to your javascript function as above.